# Как принять на PHP сервере post запрос с ReactJS

Tags: php, reactjs

Как принять на PHP сервере post запрос с ReactJS

Comment: Принимаете как обычный запрос

Comment: `$_POST` ??????

Answer (score -1):

```
$newHero = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if(isset($newHero) && !empty($newHero)){
        $request = json_decode($newHero);
}
```